# Mapbox not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I've been working on a map using some examples from the codepen website to help me get started, I have it working perfectly on Codepen see:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwQypp

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjeW1hY2dyZWdvciIsImEiOiJjaWloeTdkMDUwMGczdmptNTY2ZjA2MHZiIn0.qXQoVxn6rd7mivY1E8p4qQ';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.dark')
  .setView([-41.015506, 173.596058], 6);
```

When I try and export it from codepen so I can put it into my website, it comes up really strangely https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDdjU.jpg

I'm really new to Mapbox and my client got really excited for it, and now for some reason its not working on my actual webpage, help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: A similar behaviour happens when the corresponding library CSS is not added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance you are missing the library (Mapbox) CSS in your HTML page.

Because Leaflet (on which Mapbox is built) loads tiles starting from the center of the view, their order is not from top left to bottom right. With the CSS the library can then force the absolute position of the tiles.

But if that CSS file is missing, tiles just appear in the order they are loaded.

See https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-js/#using-mapboxjs which also gives you the URL's to use for the correct CSS and JavaScript files to include.